# NodeJS request.files returning null

Tags: node.js

I am making a small program in NodeJs and I came across a problem. I was trying to upload a pic to my server that was given by a client. Here's the NodeJs code.

```
app.post("/profile-client-save", (req, resp) => {
console.log(req.files);  });
```

The problem is that req.files keeps returning null. I imported express-fileupload. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you show us how you are using `express-fileupload`?

Comment: Here - 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
var fileup = require("express-fileupload");
app.use(fileup());

Comment: Include that in your question including weather you called `app.use()` before or after your `app.post()`

Comment: I am calling app.post

Comment: I mean, don't just answer here in the comment. We still cannot see how your code looks like. Add the relevant `app.use()` to your question above. It makes a difference weather you did `app.use(fileup()); app.post('/profile-client-save')` or `app.post('/profile-client-save'); app.use(fileup())`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:
Try

```js
formData.append('file', {
  uri: file[0].uri,
  type: file[0].type,
  name: file[0].fileName
})
```

Instead of:

```js
formData.append("file", file);
```